# fqcn-builtins: Use FQCN for builtin actions in Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I am working on Automatic deployment using ansible and helm chart. When i try to run my ansible playbook and before that i am trying to find the linting of my ansibles roles. I have cleared most of the warnings which raised during the ansible lint test.

But I don't understand "fqcn-builtins: Use FQCN for builtin actions" . Can anyone tell me how to resolve this issue and I could see in almost all of my playbook.

```
fqcn-builtins: Use FQCN for builtin actions.
main.yml:43 Task/Handler: Remove local image
fqcn-builtins: Use FQCN for builtin actions.
main.yml:48 Task/Handler: output message
fqcn-builtins: Use FQCN for builtin actions.
main.yml:64 Task/Handler: Remove local image
fqcn-builtins: Use FQCN for builtin actions.
main.yml:69 Task/Handler: output message
fqcn-builtins: Use FQCN for builtin actions.
main.yml:85 Task/Handler: Remove local image
fqcn-builtins: Use FQCN for builtin actions.
main.yml:90 Task/Handler: output message
fqcn-builtins: Use FQCN for builtin actions.
```

Sample playbook from my file

```
- name: Remove local image
  shell: docker image rm {{ image.docker_image_main }}:{{ imageTag }}
  register: imagedelete
  changed_when: "'untagged' in imagedelete.stdout"
  # noqa command-instead-of-shell
- name: output message
  debug:
    msg: "{{ imagedelete.stdout }}"
  become: "yes"
```

[Image from the pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBr1r.jpg)

Comment: They have documentation for what every one of those rules means, including [`fqcn-builtins`](https://ansible-lint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/default_rules/#fqcn-builtins), with the tl;dr of: don't use `shell:` use `ansible.builtin.shell:` and the same for its `debug:` friend

Comment: Thank you mdaniel , but i have never used this FQCN in any of my playbooks earlier. Even the ansible lint never showed such warning previously. Is this any new updation in the version of ansible?.

Comment: That message is coming from `ansible-lint`, and is (of course) optional. Ansible, itself, doesn't care and will silently redirect usages to their fully qualified version. If you don't agree with that lint rule, the ansible-lint website has instructions for suppressing it

Comment: Yes, that only started happening recently so I suppose it's a new update to ansible lint

Comment: Thank you, I understand the FQCN warnings is new warning added to ansible lint version 6 and above. I could overcome this issue by pinned version of the ansible-lint-5.4.0 in my gitlab runner Dockerfile and it vanished.

Answer (score 11):

FQCN stands for "fully qualified collection name".
You need to specify the fully qualified collection name in ansilbe playbook.

In your examples, you are using the "shell" module whose FQCN is `ansible.builtin.shell`.

In you playbook , you need add `ansible.builtin.shell` instead of `shell`

Comment: And just for extra clarity, slurp becomes ansible.builtin.slurp, etc.

Answer (score 7):

Starting from [ansible-lint 6](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-lint/releases/tag/v6.0.0), this rule is implicit by default.

[You can opt-out of this behavior](https://ansible-lint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuring/#configuration-file) by creating an `.ansible-lint` file (if not already present) and adding the content below

```
skip_list:
  - 'fqcn-builtins'
```

Another alternative is to use a specific version of ansible-lint (5.x) until you're ready to upgrade,

Comment: Yes , you are 100% right. I could over come by using lower version of ansible lint

Answer (score 2):

if you want to skip the `fqcn` and following @Abdellah Alaoui, on the new version of `ansible-lint` (ansible-lint 6.11.0 using ansible 2.13.7), you will have to add additional skip rules on your `.ansible-lint` file

```
skip_list:
  - fqcn-builtins
  - fqcn[action]
  - fqcn[action-core]
  - fqcn[canonical]
  - name[casing]
```

more on: https://ansible-lint.readthedocs.io/rules/fqcn/#problematic-code

Answer (score 0):

if you look at the documentation

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html

this means shell is in the ansible builtin collection
you just have to use the fqcn name like this

```
- name: Execute the command in remote shell; stdout goes to the specified file on the remote
  ansible.builtin.shell: somescript.sh >> somelog.txt
```